# What is a device that scans the network it is connected to called?

Tags: network, hardware, network-scanners

Are there any devices (computer, switch, router, etc.) witch integrate licensed software like Nessus or Nexpose  in a way that you can just drop them in a network and scan that network remote? If so, what are those devices called?

Example:
I buy that nice shiny box and I put it in your network and I start to scan your network.

Comment: These are fairly common with vulnerability assessment companies, but tend to be given specific brand names tied to their product offerings (e.g. "Platinum Ultrascanner") rather than a generic term. Also only tend to be offered as part of an ongoing support contract, rather than for one-off purchase, which makes sense - an unsupported third party box on a network is commonly known as a "hole" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know a few like:

- Pwn Pro
- Secpoint Penetrator

But I don't know the exact generic name of those devices and I don't think there is one.